# How to Add/Append to external JSON file using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've got a json file that I would like to build a form that will allow me to add / edit elements in the file. Is there a jQuery function/ method that will allow me to be able to post and append elements in the external json file?

Not sure if this will help but the current json structure is as follow:

```js
 [ { "cast" : "",
    "director" : "",
    "genre" : "",
    "id" : false,
    "nrVotes" : 0,
    "plot" : "",
    "rating" : 0,
    "runtime" : 0,
    "title" : "",
    "year" : false
  },
  { "cast" : "Tim Robbins, Morgan Freeman, Bob Gunton, ",
    "director" : "Frank Darabont",
    "genre" : "Crime Drama ",
    "id" : "0111161",
    "nrVotes" : 968510,
    "plot" : "Two imprisoned men bond over a number of years, finding solace and eventual redemption through acts of common decency.",
    "rating" : 9.3000000000000007,
    "runtime" : 142,
    "title" : "The Shawshank Redemption",
    "year" : "1994"
  }]
```

### Huge thank you in advance!! (:

Comment: How are you currently getting the JSON file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are using jQuery's [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) or [parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON), you have a javascript object you can manipulate. for example:

```
$.getJSON( "/test.json", function( data ) {
  // now data is JSON converted to an object / array for you to use.
  alert( data[1].cast ) // Tim Robbins, Morgan Freeman, Bob Gunton

  var newMovie = {cast:'Jack Nicholson', director:...} // a new movie object

  // add a new movie to the set
  data.push(newMovie);      
});
```

All you have to do now is save the file. You can use jQuery.post() to send the file back to the server to save it for you.

*Update: Posting an example*

```
//inside getJSON()

var newData = JSON.stringify(data);
jQuery.post('http://example.com/saveJson.php', {
    newData: newData
}, function(response){
    // response could contain the url of the newly saved file
})
```

On your server, example using PHP

```
$updatedData = $_POST['newData'];
// please validate the data you are expecting for security
file_put_contents('path/to/thefile.json', $updatedData);
//return the url to the saved file
```

Comment: @akshaynagpal, you will post the updated json as `data`, not as a `file`. I'll update the answer

Comment: myServerUrl will be just the server url or /update.php has to be included?

Comment: The **exact** url. Obviously, if it includes `update.php`, then you must include it.

Comment: Please ask a new question @akshaynagpal.

Comment: There's already a question -   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423976/saving-json-data-to-json-file-using-ajax-php

Comment: You're JSON encoding the data in your AJAX post and then you're JSON encode the data AGAIN in your PHP file, as you save it.

Comment: Yes, and you send that JSON string to the server, but then you `json_encode` the data again in PHP, when it already is JSON.

Comment: I am accounting for the comment `//please validate the data you are expecting for security` where you would probably decode the data first, but I've changed it for clarity

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $str = file_get_contents('data.json');//get contents of your json file and store it in a string
        $arr = json_decode($str, true);//decode it
         $arrne['name'] = "sadaadad";
         $arrne['password'] = "sadaadad";
         $arrne['nickname'] = "sadaadad";
         array_push( $arr['employees'], $arrne);//push contents to ur decoded array i.e $arr
         $str = json_encode($arr);
        //now send evrything to ur data.json file using folowing code
         if (json_decode($str) != null)
           {
             $file = fopen('data.json','w');
             fwrite($file, $str);
             fclose($file);
           }
           else
           {
             //  invalid JSON, handle the error 
           }

        ?>
    <form method=>
</body>
```

**data.json**

```
{  
  "employees":[  
  {  
     "email":"11BD1A05G9",
     "password":"INTRODUCTION TO ANALYTICS",
     "nickname":4
  },
  {  
     "email":"Betty",
     "password":"Layers",
     "nickname":4
  },
  {  
     "email":"Carl",
     "password":"Louis",
     "nickname":4
  },
  {  
     "name":"sadaadad",
     "password":"sadaadad",
     "nickname":"sadaadad"
  },
  {  
     "name":"sadaadad",
     "password":"sadaadad",
     "nickname":"sadaadad"
  },
  {  
     "name":"sadaadad",
     "password":"sadaadad",
     "nickname":"sadaadad"
  }
   ]
}
```