# Shiny - store javascript variable to mysql database

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, r, shiny

I am working with shiny server.
My application has a search box input. Based on that input, the output is a **dataTable** which has **clickable links**.
My application's **ui.r** contains a JavaScript function that sets the value of a variable whenever a link is clicked. Let the variable be **clickedLink**. Now I want to store this value of link to mysql or any other database. How to go about this?

I have tried ajax , php with no use. What I did is described in this question: [saving json data to json file using ajax PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423976/saving-json-data-to-json-file-using-ajax-php) but I guess php files do not work with shiny.  Please help.

**EDIT 1**

code added to ui.R

```
  tags$script(HTML("
     function clickFunction(clickedLink){
        //alert(clickedLink);
        var cl = clickedLink;
        Shiny.onInputChange('clickedLink',cl);
     }
  "))
```

code added to server.R

```
observe({
    print(input$clickedLink)

  })
```

**EDIT 2**
Just for information , the links are of the form

```
<a onclick="clickFunction(this.href); " target="_blank" href="http://SOMETING.com">SOMETHING</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you know how to save the variable once you get it in R. If not, use the RMySQL package and read their tutorial - https://github.com/rstats-db/RMySQL

So your main problem is getting the javascript variable into R. For that you can use Shiny.onInputChange.  There's a short easy tutorial here https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/

Basically, in javascript you would have
`Shiny.onInputChange("jsvar", clickedLink)` and then you can treat `jsvar` as a regular reactive input, so in R you can do `observe({ saveToDb(input$jsvar) }) (you'd have to define saveToDb)

Comment: see EDIT 1. @daattali

Comment: right, that's exactly what i suggested, looks like you're almost there. Now you just need to use RMySQL to talk to the database

Comment: But it is not returning anything. NULL only. See details, I added something.

Comment: @alloyeduniv Please prove it by a minimal reproducible example when you say anything is not working.